# how to cause ssh delay between two Linux machines

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel

we have redhat machines - version - 7.2

as all know ssh between Linux machines should be fast ( couple m seconds )

but for testing

we want to cause ssh delay between machine - linux 1 to linux 2

the delay should be more then 20 seconds

is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by 'ssh', the connection process? On low level connection is established via sockets handled by the kernel + encryption done via ssl. Once connection is established other layers start so that you can login and run the shell. Which part do you want to "delay"? Perhaps just put `sleep 20` into your .bashrc? Anyway, probably XY problem.

Comment: what I mean is that once I get the login , we need delay until we get the password prompt

Comment: You could put a pam_exec.so in the /etc/pam.d/sshd that would sleep for a period,  then you will want to make sure the protocol doesn’t time out the pam stack if it is too long.